# How to access values from setState to return in NextJs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The code below useState and useEffect is getting value from the API successfully:

```
const [user,setUser] = useState([]); 
 useEffect(()=>{ const getdata= async()=>{
    let databody = {"slugs":slug} 
    await fetch('/api/question/view', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(databody),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
    }).then(res => res.json())
     .then(data =>setUser(data)); 
    } 
    getdata(); 
  },[])
```

Data Values to user(setUser)

```
{questionsz: Array(1), questionshead: {…}, related: Array(5), morequestion: Array(10), latestjobs: Array(5), …}
questionshead:
ans: "<p>who did not love </p>"
category: null
chapter: "test-1"
```

Here iam trying to access value
`{user.questionshead.ans)` its shows undefined in return
please helps how to access questionshead.ans?

Comment: could you do console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)) the data value of set user, also is this a typescript issue, or in HTML the value is not visible?

Comment: Could you add the code that follows useEffect? How and where are you accessing `user.questionshead.ans`?

Comment: Can you try to change `user.questionshead.ans` to `user?.questionshead?.ans`

Comment: `{user?.questionshead?.mtitle?user.questionshead.mtitle:""}` provides empty

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo
  `return(<div> {user?.questionshead?.mtitle?user.questionshead.mtitle:""}</div>)`